# How do implement HTTPS on super simple Django site

Tags: django

I built a simple page with Django from this tutorial https://wsvincent.com/django-image-uploads/.

How do I enable https on it so that the uploaded posts can not be seen in the clear on the network?

I currently not running apache, tomcat or Nginx but can if that is the only way.

I read the SSL/HTTPS of the Django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/security/#ssl-https on Django security but is that something I configure within the Django framework or are those settings for a web server like Apache.
Thank you.

Comment: You will need to implement a proper server *anyway*; that is the time to enable HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used or heard of CloudFlare? (for speed but also a free enabling of HTTPS)

**Link**: https://www.cloudflare.com/lp/overview-x/?_bt=308976257739&_bk=cloudflare&_bm=e&_bn=g&_bg=58800278543&_displaycampaign=&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIhtfCr7CJ4gIVzbHtCh38jwvKEAAYASAAEgKnOPD_BwE

You simply enter the URL of your website (if it is all set up) and then enable HTTPS. Read their terms and conditions of course, but it is fantastic.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm trying to host it locally.